# How to append to MANPATH?

Tags: man

If the `MANPATH` environment variable is set, `man` very "helpfully" ignores the default search path, as defined in `/etc/manpath.config`. Is there any way add a path or paths to that searched by `man`?

Answer (score 12):

It depends on the `man` implementation, but since you have `/etc/manpath.config` I'm guessing that you're using a Debian-derived system with man-db.

In that case, [manpath(1)](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/man-db/manpath.1.en.html) describes what you can do here (and the same approach will work for man(1)):

> If $MANPATH is prefixed by a colon, then the value of the variable is
>   appended to the list determined from the content of the configuration
>   files. If the colon comes at the end of the value in the variable,
>   then the determined list is appended to the content of the variable.
>   If the value of the variable contains a double colon (::), then the
>   determined list is inserted in the middle of the value, between the
>   two colons.

Comment: That explains why I have been able to get away with prefixing `/path:` to `$MANPATH` even when it starts out empty.

Comment: Better not set `MANPATH`: see answer about `~/.manpath` below,

Comment: @scrutari I mean, I'm the maintainer of man-db :-)  It's true that `~/.manpath` is more flexible, but it's also that bit more complex to configure as a result of that flexibility, as compared with `MANPATH` which has obvious analogies with `PATH`.  If all you need is to adjust the search path then I think it's perfectly reasonable to use the environment variable approach.

Answer (score 11):

Depending on the particular implementation of `man`, you may augment the value of `MANPATH` in different ways.

On Linux systems, set `MANPATH` to the value of `manpath -g`:

```
export MANPATH="$(manpath -g):/new/path/man"
```

or create an alias like

```
alias man='man -M "$(manpath -g):/new/path/man"'
```

On FreeBSD, do as above, but drop the `-g`.

On OpenBSD and NetBSD, use

```
alias man='man -m /new/path/man'
```

Consult the manual for the `man` utility on your Unix.

Comment: Better not set `MANPATH`: see answer about `~/.manpath` below,

Comment: @scrutari There is no indication in your comment how this applies to my answer. Comments are primarily for suggesting improvements to answers, but you should also be able to improve by suggesting edits directly.

Answer (score 8):

Don't set `MANPATH` env variable.

You can add any number of custom paths to your local `~/.manpath` file:

```
MANDATORY_MANPATH /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/doc/man
```

That is for a TeXlive distribution installed on `/usr/local/texlive`. This file can have any number of such entries.

Also, if you have some custom `/path/to/some/bin` on your `PATH`, where `/path/to/some/bin/..` has any of these subdirectories `man`, `bin/man`, `share/man`, or `share/man`, this man path will be added automatically (unless you prevent it by setting the `MANPATH` env variable).

You can check how paths are picked up by `man` by running

```
manpath -d
```

Comment: This is the correct answer: this way does not corrupt any global configuration, so it is the most safe one.

Comment: @scrutari Unfortunately, this answer does not say what Unix this applies to.  Note that the question does not specify explicitly what Unix they are using. Also note that the environment variable `MANPATH` is modifiable per user, just like any environment variable, and just like the `~/.manpath` file.

Comment: @scrutari Setting an environment variable doesn't "corrupt any global configuration" either.

Comment: I don't see any mention of `~/.manpath` in the MacOS man page for `man`. Is this GNU-specific feature?

Comment: I can confirm that the `~/.manpath` approach works under Bluehost's CentOS 7 (I believe that's what they're running) in shared hosting. Well done :)

Comment: Grr... Why doesn't `man manpath` contain this detail? (`man man` mentions it, though)

Comment: This (~/.manpath) doesn't work for my Raspberry Pi or Debian systems.